# Why is 365 days equal to 80000 years?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) `interval` and wanted to get the number of days as integer. However I get the following strange intermediate results:

```
library("lubridate")
i1 <- interval("2015-01-01 00:00:00", "2016-01-01 00:00:00")
i1 <- interval(ymd_hms("2015-01-01 00:00:00"), ymd_hms("2016-01-01 00:00:00")) # Gives the same result
duration(i1)
# [1] "31536000s (~365 days)"
duration(i1, units = "days")
# [1] "2724710400000s (~86340.86 years)"
```

Here are two working shortcuts. The latter throws a message "coercing interval to duration" (And I don't know the reason for that...)

```
> as.numeric(as.duration(i1), units = "days")
[1] 365
> as.numeric(i1, units = 'days')
```

(R version 3.3.0 dated 2016-05-03, lubridate version 1.5.6.)

Comment: Without knowing `r` at all, I can tell you that there are 86,400 seconds/day, and guess that you are getting some kind of double conversion.

Comment: Durations only store data as seconds for consistency. Use periods, which are more flexible about units: `p1 <- as.period(i1, unit = 'days') ; p1 ; day(p1)`. Note that 365 days and 1 year are not necessarily the same thing due to leap years, and lubridate was built with that in mind.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You misunderstand the meaning of the `units` argument. From the documentation,

> units a character string that specifies the type of units that `num`
>   refers to.

where `num` is the first argument. So

```
duration(i1)
```

is equivalent to

```
duration(i1, units = "seconds")
```

However,

```
duration(i1, units = "days")
```

means that `i1` is measured in `days`; hence the very large number.

Comment: It’s a bit odd (I’d call it a bug) that the `units` argument should override the unit of the given value.

Comment: I think it's a bit confusing to. I initially assumed that `units` would affect the result, instead of the argument.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's not a bug, it's a feature! :-) Seriously though, that's what it is. If you check the code of duration(), it never reads the unit of any class, and just treats the num argument as a normal vector. I would have created a method for an interval object, but that didn't happen. You might suggest it to the authors though.

Comment: @csgillespie: Is there a function where you can specify the output by a unit? When dealing with dates this seems to be a nice and clear feature.

Answer (score 9):

[According to the maintainer](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/462#issuecomment-242703677),

> [using `duration` on an `interval` object] should be disallowed. For conversion use `as.duration`.

In addition, the bug in the above code is now fixed by disallowing the function call:

```
> duration(i1)
Error in .duration_from_num(num, units) :
  First argument to `duration` constructor must be character or numeric. Supplied object of class 'Interval'
> as.duration(i1)
[1] "31536000s (~52.14 weeks)"
```

Comment: it seems that `as.duration` also does not work that way. See my edit.

Comment: @Christoph You aren’t using the function correctly, `as.duration` has no `units` argument, and the function’s purpose isn’t to control the display unit, but simply to convert a measure into a duration (same as `duration`).

Comment: You are right, but I am confused: I would like to have the duration of `i1` in days. What is the way I should do that? (`duration(i1)/24/3600` yields 
 `"365s (~6.08 minutes)"` which is wrong. `as.numeric(as.duration(i1), units = "days")` is doing the job, but why do I then need `duration` or `as.duration`?

Comment: Rudolf: Sorry, now I have a more precise question. Why is there no shortcut for `as.numeric(as.duration(i1), units = "whatever unit")`?

Comment: @Christoph There is: `as.numeric(i1, units = 'days')` works. No need to convert to a duration.

Comment: Rudolf: This throws a message `coercing interval to duration`. Normally, there is a reason for such messages?

Comment: @Christoph You may have to update your `lubridate` installation. At any rate, no such message is generated for me using the newest version of lubridate.

Comment: @Rudolf: Strange, my lubridate version 1.5.6 is up to date. But thank you for your help!